# Possible xml deserialization bug

Tags: xml, c#-3.0, xsd, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I'm using the following xml schema entry to deserliaze some xml into an xsd generated block.

```
<xs:element name="Action">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string" use="required" />
   <xs:attribute name="dst" type="xs:string" use="required" />
   <xs:attribute name="create" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
   <xs:attribute name="transform" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For some reason when I have the block

```
 <Action src="..."
         dst=".."
         create="yes"/>
```

Its returning the src and destination attributes correctly, but it's also returning create and transform as "yes". The transform attribute should be null. Anybody know whats going on. Is my wee schema wrong somehow?

Thanks.
Bob.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's seems that the xml deseraliser gets confused if you don't have unique element names.